# Seeking API for live ASOS/AWOS reports

Tags: api, weather

Many weather apps and websites are now including airport ASOS/AWOS weather reports. (All the colored dots in the below screenshot, from [SkyVector](http://SkyVector.com))

[image]

I'd like to find the API for getting the NOAA (NWS?) data feed. So far, nothing has jumped out at me in my searches, although I have found https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/weather/asos/ where I could scrape the site for data.

Comment: csv's dowloadable from https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-hourly/access/2021/

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at those CSVs and they seem to be yearly historic datasets for worldwide airport reporting stations (cool!), not necessarily the latest report from US airports. It would be challenging to use those data sets for live up-to-date weather reports.

Comment: I think this belons on the OpenData SE

Comment: @alphabetasoup Brilliant! I had no idea that group existed. If a mod could migrate this over there, it seems to be a perfect fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been searching for something similar. So far this is the best API I have found (for free). Just looking to make a site for a fun side project.

API Swagger doc:
https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/api/1/docs#/default/

Main site to play around with and look for the "network" you want to query:
https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/sites/locate.php?

I have not gone through all of the endpoints but found the /current.{fmt} to have at least the basics of what I'm going for.

Comment: That's pretty good. Looks like a query such as https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/json/current.py?network=MA_ASOS&station=BOS returns exactly the relevant data in a JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

The point data shown in the [SkyVector](http://skyvector.com) map is listed as METAR/TAF

METAR/TAF data can be obtained from NOAA through the following page:

https://aviationweather.gov/metar

A request for METAR/TAF data for the last 120 hours would be:

https://aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=&format=raw&date=&hours=120

Looking at the  data acknowledgements on the SkyVector page it would appear that the weather data most likely comes via [ARINC](https://www.arincdirect.com/), who may add the  geographical location.

Comment: This is almost the right answer, except that the information cannot be directly consumed in that format. The entire web page would have to be stripped off first. Setting layout=off seems to reduce the cruft, e.g. https://aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kiob&format=raw&hours=0&taf=off&layout=off, but it's still not quite there. Even in the minimal state, the payload-- i.e. the METAR-- is <2% of the downloaded data so it's not really practical as an API.